# Python lib to make nice command line scripts with options etc

Tags: python

I remember coming reading about a python module/lib that helped make nice command line scripts that takes in options.

My python script (1 file) does many things, and currently I comment out/uncomment the function I want run in my **main** section.

I was hoping someone knows the lib I'm talking about that would help me organize the various functions and call them when I run the .py script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

there is an `optparse` module.  in newer variants of python, `argparse` is preferred.

optparse: http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html

argparse: http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html

use optparse in <= 2.7, argparse in > 2.7

Comment: define all of the functions you want and then call them based on the argument.

Comment: @Blankman: You should accept some answers (this question and other questions asked earlier). Use the big 'tick' to accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Python’s optparse for human beings](http://www.alexonlinux.com/pythons-optparse-for-human-beings)